# Ajax Error returning "Text"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this Ajax code running on my web page (asp.net razor)

```
$(document).on('click', '#search-results tr', function (event) {
    //Add to cart
    var id = $(this).find('#SKU').val();
    var userId = $('#ID').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/orders/AddtoCart",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "productId": id, "Quantity": 1, "UserID": userId, "Description": "" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.debug("Added to cart");
            //ajax call to DraftOrderDetailsLineItems to refresh the lines 
            $.get('/Orders/DraftOrderDetailsLineItems/', { customerId: data.id }, function (data) {
                $("#draftOrderItems").html(data);
            })
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("[Error in Ajax Request, Add To Cart] Code:" + jqXHR.status + " Error:" + errorThrown + " \nText Status:" + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

I put a breakpoint in my controller and it is calling the AddtoCart method just fine. However when I look in my console I am getting this error:

> VM247 DraftOrderDetails.js:19 [Error in Ajax Request, Add To Cart] Code:0 Error: 
>   Text Status:undefined

I have been looking this over and I just can't seem to find out what is going one.

Comment: Would you share server side codes ?

Comment: My guess is that the controller isn't returning valid JSON. Go to the Network tab of the console and look at the raw response. It might have error messages or HTML around the JSON.

Comment: Should `customerId` have quotes? 3rd line inside 'success'.

Comment: @wazz No, object keys don't need quotes. If they did, you'd also have to write `"url":`, `"success":`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was an error from the controller of all places.  The controller was throwing an uncaught error which was spitting out this ajax error (which technically wasn't an error).  Once we trapped the error in the controller, the ajax error went away.  Just posting this in case someone else sees this and hopefully will be pointed to another possible cause of the error.